# I can login via Facebook, but other users can't

Tags: playframework-2.2, play-authenticate

I am setting up a new Play-Authenticate. I have Google and Facebook enabled. Google seems to work for everyone that has tested it, however Facebook only works for me. Other Facebook users in the office (2 people) receive the following message....

"**App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login.**"

I have let them try using my workstation AND browser, and Facebook still only works for me.

It must have something to do with the way I created the Facebook application, but I am not seeing it.

tia, Chet

Comment: It works for you because you're the owner of the Facebook application, however you didn't set the correct permissions on that application so that others can also log in.

Comment: I hadn't made the site "live/published" by submitting it for approval in the status section. I didn’t have to do this for Google authentication.

Answer (score 0):

That occurs because your app is not yet in live mode. You got a couple of ways to solve this out:

First, to test your app facebook provides the option to create "Test Users" for your app, which you can use as you intend to get your app done (they give you the username, password and other settings stuff).

Second, authorize your friends or so to be testers of the app. They have to accept the facebook developer's terms before they can use their account to test your app.

(This might come a little out of time but I hope it works as well for you and everyone around here!)

Good Luck